# Foreign key relationship, related object not storing properly in DbContext?

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, entity-framework

Despite I'm completely new to .NET stack, I somehow managed to develop a small N-Tier application involving the following technologies:

WPF -> WCF -> Entity Framework -> SQL Server

My doubt is mainly about how Entity Framework manages the assignment of navigation properties. I'll put my data contract code to get the ball rollin' ...

```
[DataContract]
public class Problem
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ProblemId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String Title { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String Description { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int WorkerId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int WorkId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [ForeignKey("WorkerId")]        
    public virtual Worker Worker { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [ForeignKey("WorkId")]        
    public virtual Work Work { get; set; }
}


[DataContract]
public class Worker
{
    [DataMember]
    public int WorkerId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String Name { get; set; }    

    [DataMember] 
    public virtual ICollection<Problem> Problems { get; set; }        
}


[DataContract]
public class Work
{
    [DataMember]
    public int WorkId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String Name { get; set; }      

    [DataMember] 
    public virtual ICollection<Problem> Problems { get; set; }
}
```

In my Seed method, I'm doing the following:

```
Work Work1 = new Work()
                                {
                                    WorkId = 1,
                                    Name = "Work1"
                                };

        Worker emp1 = new Worker()
                                {
                                    WorkerId = 1,
                                    Name = "Worker1"
                                };

        Problem Problem1 = new Problem()
                            {
                                ...
                                WorkId = 1,
                                WorkerId = 1
                            };

        Problem Problem2 = new Problem()
                              {
                                  ...
                                  Work = Work1,
                                  Worker = emp1
                              };

        //add objects to the context
        context.Works.Add(Work1);
        context.Workers.Add(emp1);
        context.Problems.Add(Problem1);
        context.Problems.Add(Problem2);

        //added just for testing
        Problem1.Work = Work1;
        Problem1.Worker = emp1;

        //finally: save changes           
        context.SaveChanges();
```

And the point is: after disposing the context & doing a query like: context.Problems.ToList() ... both problem1 & problem2 have its navigation properties (Worker, Work) assigned to Null. WorkerId and WorkId are stored, but no its related Objects inside the Problem Entity.

Am I missing something?

Thank you very much in advance for your answer!

Comment: Please notice that I'm creating "Problem" objects in two different ways (assigning their related Work&Worker by their Id & by their navigation property directly). This is not a typo, or mistake, or whatever. I was only trying to detect why was this happening, and with the 2 ways of initializing the "Problem"s ... the result is the same! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to do

```
context.Problems.Include(p=>p.Work).ToList()
```

in order to populate the children when you reload them under a new context.

Comment: Thank you very much Justin!

I've tried that, but getting a "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type" :S

Comment: Ah, I know what that is, you need to add: using System.Data.Entity

Comment: Wow, you're the man Justin! It's working fine now. This helps me a lot while doing the Data Binding from the WPF Client side :-)